# После динамической подгрузки контента не срабатывает событие

Tags: jquery, input

Не срабатывает обработчик в `input`, после подгрузки контента на странице

```
$('#fm').bind("change keyup input click", function() {

alert('ok');

})
```

Comment: Пробовал так $('#ff').on('input', function () {})

Comment: `#ff` это у вас родительский элемент внутри которого меняется контент?

Comment: При динамической подгрузке элементов если событие является всплывающим, то его можно отлавливать через .on на родительском элементе с указанием типа дочернего элемента, вопрос - мега баян